# Javascript Windows Azure Mobile Service Client With Custom API

Tags: javascript, api, azure-mobile-services

I am attempting to call a custom api with javascript created in Windows Azure Mobile Services and I am having an issue with getting the results in the callback/promise.

I have tested it with fiddler and the data object is being returned with the correct data however it is not passing that data to the callback.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Below is the code segment I am using:

```
client.invokeApi('NameOfApi', {
            method: 'GET',
            parameters: { organizationId: organizationID }
        }).done(function (results) {
            var requests = JSON.parse(results.response);
            //Do some stuffz with requests collection
        }, function (error) {
            alert(error);
        });
```

And in doing so I am getting into the `done` or `error` callbacks through debugging methods. However I have verified that the results are coming back from the api call but they never reached the promise for some reason.

Comment: Please add some code of what you're doing. Also, do you have na error callback? That could show why the (success) callback isn't being called.

Comment: @carlosfigueira code has been attached Thanks

Comment: When you call `client.invokeApi`, are you saying that **neither** the success nor the error callbacks are being called? Also, is this a HTML/JavaScript project, or a Windows Store/JavaScript app?

Comment: @carlosfigueira It is a HTML/Javascript project and yes the success nor error callbacks are called on IE 9

Comment: Found out the issue occurs in IE 9. It works in other browsers…….???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue you described is a known bug with IE9 and MobileServices.Web-1.0.0.js. This bug has been addressed in version 1.0.3 and later. Details can be found here: https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-mobile-services/issues/152

Updating your project to use the latest version at: http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mobileservices/MobileServices.Web-1.1.0.min.js

Will resolve this for you.